# Example of Ring Homomorphism such that inverse image of maximal ideal is not maximal.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Give an example of a ring homomorphism $f : R \rightarrow S$ and a maximal ideal $M \unlhd S$ such that $f^{-1}(M) \subset R$ is not a maximal ideal. 
The example I came up with is $f : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[[x]]$ by $f(x) = x$ and the maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$ is $(x)$. Then I obtained that $f^{-1}(M) = \{0\}$ which is not a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$, take for example $\{0 \} \subset (p) \subset \mathbb{Z}$. Is this a correct example?

Comment: $f(x)=x$ has no meaning. Other things are valid. A more concise example is to remove the $x$. That is, simply $\mathbb{Q}$ instead of $\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$, and the ideal (0) of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I meant that $f$ is the inclusion map. Also, are maximal ideals allowed to be $\{0\}$ or $M$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the example is correct (although you should use a different letter for defining $f$, because $x$ is already a *particular* element of $\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$), but any domain $R$ (not a field) and its field of quotients $F$ provide for an example.

The simplest instance is $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$. The inverse image of the maximal ideal $(0)$ is the ideal $(0)$ which is not maximal in $\mathbb{Z}$.

This is an instance of a more general situation. Any time you have a commutative ring $R$, having a nonmaximal prime ideal $P$, the localization of $R$ at $P$ has a unique maximal ideal, whose inverse image under the localization map is $P$.

Comment: do we define maximal ideals to not be $\{ 0 \}$ or can they be $0$?

Comment: @user100101212 The ideal $(0)$ is a maximal ideal of the commutative ring $R$ if and only if $R$ is a field. So yes, $(0)$ can be a maximal ideal.

Comment: @user100101212 Given an ideal $I$, we say it is $\textbf{maximal}$ if whenever there is another ideal $J$ such that $I\subseteq J$, we have $J=I$ or $J=R$, where $R$ is the ring considered. This is pretty much the very definition of maximal ideals, and so here, yes, $\{0\}$ is a maximal ideal in that $\mathbb Q$ doesn't have any other proper ideal except $\{0\}$.